# Importing java class in python module

Tags: python, jython

I have created one package in Java and one publis class inside it.

```
package GX1164;
public class Test
{
    public int add(int a)
    {
    return (a+a);
    }
}
```

Now I have to import this package and class in python module to call the function "add".
But somehow I am not able to import the class Test. I keep getting the error "Undefined module Test"

Comment: I take it you're using Jython rather than CPython?

Comment: Come on thats not fair to give him -2 just because he forgot to say jython as a tag.

Comment: I actually think the question is very clear. Sure he forgot to mention he was working with jython but thats no reason to close it.

Answer (score 3):

Build your java class into a .jar file then do the following
Appending the jar to sys.path is the same as setting a class path.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("GX1164.jar")

import GX1164

test = GX1146.Test()
print test.add(42)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, your module is called `GX1164` and the class is called `Test`:

```
import GX1164
test = GX1164.Test()
print test.add(42)
```

You also need to make sure that the `CLASSPATH` is set up in a manner that will allow Jython to find `Test.class`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this. I am getting some errors.

Comment: A.S.SASTE tried to edit this answer with a comment. [Here's the traceback](http://pastebin.com/Rz4yyQGS) he posted.